# RestKit 0.20 and ManagedObjectContexts

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am mapping data using RestKit 0.20 into a Core Data and displaying it in a UITable. I am writing the data, an 'Activity' object, to the mainQueue's ManagedObjectContext and it all works fine. Now I need a second table with Future-Activities and also a third table with Past-Activities. I need a ManagedObjectContext for each table as the sorting is done on the server side. How can I handle this and have persistent data. Is 'newChildManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType' what I need to use?

Comment: You don't need a different context (really, persistent store) for this. You need some way to tag your `Activity` objects so you know what they are for. What is the JSON you receive? Can you use some of the request metadata?

Comment: I use different Url arguments for each case (all, future or past) so the payload has exactly what I need and sorted asc/desc. But if I display past Activities and then hit the future button, I have to wait for a new payload to display future Activities. If I already had the data in a persistent store, and it didn't change, then the User wouldn't even notice any delay at all. That's my aim if possible.

Comment: And to answer your question, the Json has the following fields: "all_day" "start_time" "end_time" so I could use them to display data until the payload arrives.

Comment: Couldn't you simply fetch "all" activities, persist them to the store and then use predicates to separate them to your categories?

Comment: I could do that. As I am also paging I would have to be handling predicates and the paging. So if I paged 2 pages on all-activities, switched to future-activities then I have to purge the ManagedObject when I receive the new payload with future-activities. If I then switch back to all-activities I would have lost my 2 pages from earlier. Seems like I would have to cover many angles when the server is delivering exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a single store. Use a predicate to filter out the items you want.

If you can download all of the data (and you're happy to do that even though some of it may not be used by the user), and you can tag them for what they are used for then that is an option.

From a RestKit point of view, you can use metadata to tag the items during the mapping process so that you know how they should be used (and then filter on that). This requires that you add a new key to the item - but, if one item could be in all responses this will be problematic because the values would get overwritten.

To use metadata, simply add a new mapping like:

```
@"@metadata.URL": @"requestURL"
```

Where `@metadata.URL` is the URL used to make the request and `requestURL` is the property on your entity that you can use for filtering. The predicate will check for `contains` your types ("all_day" "start_time" "end_time").

Comment: I am going to go with this answer. Each item can be filtered from it's URL for all, future and past. More I wouldn't have to do. But how do I send @metadata.URL for RKPaginator? Examples I see use RKMappingOperation, so how do I connect them?

Comment: You don't. Metadata is made available to the mapping. The pagination creates the URL.

Comment: I must be missing something: I added a string property 'requestURL' to my Activitiy Entity and @"@metadata.URL": @"requestURL" to my RKEntityMapping. But requestURL is nil and not mapped. Log output is: Did not find mappable attribute value keypath '@metadata.URL'

Comment: You added it to a response mapping, yes? This is something where we're grabbing extra information while processing the response (paginator is for the request).

Comment: Yes, I added it to the reponse mapping only. So I need to add it to the RequestMapping first, as in @"@metadata.MyUrlString": @"requestURL", and then I get "MyUrlString" mapped back in the response mapping. Is that how it works?

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the request at all.

Comment: Ok, so then I don't get what I am missing and why it is not mapping. I added the 'requestURL' to my Activitiy Entity and @"@metadata.URL": @"requestURL" to the RKEntityMapping of the reponse mapping. And that should do the trick, correct? That's really all I need?

Comment: Got it to work by changing @"@metadata.URL" to @'@metadata.HTTP.request.URL.absoluteString' because I saw that in a crash report under RestKit issues on Github. A fluke on my side I guess....

Comment: Yes. RestKit documentation needs updated as well. I haven't used the URL metadata for a few months, maybe the docs were always wrong...